# Constructing a (n-1) dimensional manifold transversal to a vector in n dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-topology

I am trying to construct (locally or globally) a n-1 dimensional transversal manifold for a vector with dimensions n. For example, in case of n = 3, the manifold would be a surface that intersects with the three dimensional vector transversally. In case of n = 2, the manifold would be a line that transversally intersects the two dimensional vector.

I need to find a general mathematical algorithm to construct this (n-1) manifold for a vector space of dimension n.

Thanks!

Comment: Just take the orthogonal hyperplane?

Comment: What do you mean by a vector in this context? Do you mean a line segment?